# Departure_time on Google Maps Distance Matrix API (Web Service) WITH Business license

Tags: python, google-maps

I have a Google Maps API for Business license. I still cannot get a response that includes duration time in current traffic. Here is example python code that I'm working with.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time
import urllib.parse
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import urllib.request


# Set variables.
client_id = 'gme-DUMMY'
crypto_key = 'DUMMY'
url_base = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'


# Construct URL. ---------------------------------------------------------------
query_args = { 'origins':'2097 Honeysuckle Lane Southwest, Atlanta, GA 30311, USA',
               'destinations':'67 Fitzgerald Street Southeast, Atlanta, GA 30312, USA',
               'client':client_id,
               'departure_time':time.time()  # +2*60 or +5*60 does nothing
         }
encoded_args = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_args)
url = url_base + encoded_args


# Get encoded_signature. -------------------------------------------------------
# Remove the 'https://' from url.
url_parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
url_to_sign = url_parsed.path + "?" + url_parsed.query

# Decode crypto_key into its binary format.
decoded_key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(crypto_key)

# Create a signature using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
signature = hmac.new(decoded_key, url_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha1)

# Encode the binary signature into base64 for use within a URL.
encoded_signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest()).decode("utf-8")


# Append encoded_signature to url. ---------------------------------------------
encoded_url = url + '&signature=' + encoded_signature


# Send query. ------------------------------------------------------------------
f = urllib.request.urlopen(encoded_url)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Additional notes:

- I've tried adding two and five minutes to the `departure_time` as well, but it had no effect. (The documentation just notes that the `departure_time` should be within a few minutes from the current time.)
- I've verified that the code is working and is responding with the same duration that maps.google.com lists as the "duration without traffic."
- I've dug around StackOverflow for several hours now trying to find a question/answer where the person actually had a business license. I couldn't locate one. Please point one out if it exists.
- The above code follows [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth). It is ported to Python 3.x though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need departure time in UTC

```
query_args = { 'origins':'2097 Honeysuckle Lane Southwest, Atlanta, GA 30311, USA',
           'destinations':'67 Fitzgerald Street Southeast, Atlanta, GA 30312, USA',
           'client':client_id,
           'departure_time':calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
     }
```

Comment: Turns out you can also just use `int(time.time())`. I guess it was the floating point number that the API didn't like.